# h1/h2 text cutting off when resizing window - custom font issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

Edit: I had been using a custom font "Gotham" (downloaded folder of fonts in my project) in the @font-face which appears to be the source all of the bugs. Not really sure how to fix it though. Is there a way to fix these issues while keeping my custom font?

Edit #2: the issue has been fixed with ascent-override: 80%; in the font-face. But this doesn't work on Safari browsers. Is there any solution?

When I resize my browser's window height while testing my website, there is a horizontal invisible line cutting off my h1/h2 text. From my research, it seems to be something due to line-height, but im not sure.

Thoughts I had:

1. When I don't set a line-height for the h1/h2, their height renders to 0px and are just invisible. The p tag in the middle seems to be fine with/without line height, I don't understand why?
   see below, all line height removed
2. When it does have a line height, the text of the h1/h2 seems to be offset of the container. When I highlight the h1 in devtools, the text is higher than the box, outside of the margins.
3. When I resize my window, the 'invisible line' cutting into my text seems to be in the same spot, while my text moves up and down with the page resizing. So when the invisible line is between lines of the h2/h1, the page looks normal.
4. I have a script animating numbers that sets the innerHTML to the next number. Maybe the use of .innerHTML is screwing something up? When the animation happens, the invisible line cuts into the numbers like so. But for some reason it fixes itself when I resize the window.
5. Maybe it's the font I'm using? I'm using a custom font 'Gotham' and have it set up in the @font-face in the css.

Sorry for the bad description, but I did my best. Let me know if I could clarify anything. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: i did inspect your css , there is no 'invisible line' as you mentioned. probably there are conflict with another css ?

Comment: @MrNoob does the new picture help explain?

Answer (score 2):

I can't add a comment so adding an answer, can you not use box-sizing to resolve this?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

This should then force the h1/h2 to remain within the box rather than cutting part of it.

Comment: Please expand your example with an actual example.